# Parsing with XSL

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xpath, stylesheet

Firefox gives the following error: 
    Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

In Google Chrome it shows a blank page.

Here is the code for my .xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Curriculum Vitae</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyle.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Curriculum Vitae: Matthew Stanley Klein</h1>
    <br/>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">General Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Showreel</a></li>
    </ul>

    <xsl:for-each select="references/company">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name != ''">
                <dl>
                    <dt><xsl:value-of select="name" /></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <dl>
                            <dt>Name of Person: <xsl:value-of select="person" /></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <xsl:when test="cellphone != ''">
                                    Cellphone:  <xsl:value-of select="cellphone" />
                                </xsl:when>

                                <xsl:when test="work != ''">
                                    <br/>
                                    work: <xsl:value-of select="work" />
                                </xsl:when>

                                <xsl:when test="email != ''">
                                    <br/>
                                    email: <xsl:value-of select="email" />
                                </xsl:when>
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </xsl:when>
            <hr/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

1. `xsl:when` parent should be `xsl:choose`.
2. `xsl:choose` should contain only `xsl:when` (not `<hr/>`)

Comment: Thank you! I had to create a new <xsl:choose> for every new block of <xsl:when>

Answer (score 2):

`xsl:when` must be child of `xsl:choose`, not `<dd>`, and `xsl:choose` can only have `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` as children, not `<\hr>`.

You can use VisualStudio Express and Eclipse XML package as XSLT editors to find these things while you write them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the `<hr/>` between `</xsl:when>` and `</xsl:choose>`?

It should be either within `<xsl:when>`, or outside `<xsl:choose>`...

Comment: yup, the <hr/> should be outside the <xsl:choose>

Answer (score 1):

Use XML Spy or similar tools when writing XSLT - the tool will quickly tell you what is and what is not allowed.